# Excel file rounding off when uploaded on a website

Tags: excel, numbers

sorry if this like a dumb question to you. But if know the answer, I'm just asking for it.

Like this instance, I uploaded an excel file on the website but after I downloaded it again to retrieve it, the number in a particular cell which is 1313726 changed into 1313725. I am not sure, if it's rounding off.

I want to know why it happened and if possible how to fix it.

Thank you!

Comment: Without checking the file or a data sample, this is a shot in the darkness. Are you sure the real **value** in the cell is an integer and not a decimal? In Excel, is not the same *what you see* vs *the real value in cell* very often.

Comment: So is it possible that it has a hidden decimal, then after I upload on a website and downloaded it, it has automatically rounded off, right? Or vice versa?

Comment: As I said, without looking a data sample properly and not knowing all the details, this is a shot in the darkness. It **could** be a reason, but not 100% sure